# Which song was played before the national anthem in the world T20 2014 in Bangladesh?

Tags: cricket, trivia, media, cricket-world-cup

Can anyone name the song which was played before the national anthem in the recently concluded world T20 2014 held in Bangladesh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That theme song which played was from

**[Vangelis - conquest of paradise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYeDsa4Tw0c)**

Answer (score -1):

This was the Theme Song:

[**Theme Song of ICC T20 World Cup 2014 – Char Chokka Hoi Hoi**](http://videos.cricket.com.pk/theme-song-of-icc-t20-world-cup-2014-char-chokka-hoi-hoi-1222/)

Comment: I asked the song which played before the national anthem of two teams.  That humming like song!

Comment: No it doesn't., I asked about the song which played when the players walking out for respective national anthems

Comment: @Sukan I see. Do you happen to have a reference to this song, or is it something you heard and are trying to identify? Does [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Which+song+was+played+before+the+national+anthem+in+the+world+T20+2014+in+Bangladesh%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb) help you?